# Need help emulating a USB device using my Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-4, usb, gadget

I've tried to follow a couple examples online. I've got `dwc2` at boot, I've added `libcomposite` to my modules file. I can run the following successfully.

```
cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/
mkdir g1
cd g1
echo 0x1430 > idVendor
echo 0x0150 > idProduct
mkdir configs/c.1
echo 0x80 > configs/c.1/bmAttributes
echo 250 > configs/c.1/MaxPower
mkdir functions/hid.usb0
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/protocol
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/subclass
echo 8 > functions/hid.usb0/report_length
echo -ne '\x06\x00\xff' > functions/hid.usb0/report_desc
```

when I get to

```
mkdir configs/c.1/hid.usb0
```

I get the error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘hid.usb0’: Operation not permitted
```

This is on a Pi 4 with the latest image. Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: have you tried `ln -s functions/hid.usb0 configs/c.1/` - all examples I've seen do that :p

Comment: you're awesome. that seemed to work. i don't seem to get an in and out file for communication. any idea why this might be?

Comment: No sorry, I don't even know what the device you're trying to emulate is, so no idea what an "in and out file" could possibly be, let alone how to get one